# Probability with multiple occurrences

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble understanding the following circumstances:

Say I have a 1 in 4 chance of having a bad day at work. I work 5 days a week; what is the likelihood that I will have at least one bad day per week? What does this formula look like if I want to adjust the probability and number of occurrences? How about if I ask for the likelihood of at least 2 bad days? 3? So on.

To complicate things what if I can do something to negate a bad day result even after it's occurred? Like once per week I can buy a latte to cheer me up, making that bad day good, how can I account for change ups like this?

Comment: This is not enough information to answer.  The answer below assumes independence which is not a safe assumption (*but assuming independence is the only way you can actually get an answer with the limited information provided*).  E.g. if your pet dies on monday, then monday will be a bad day at work... as will tuesday and wednesday, etc...  Having a good day on one day will usually imply later days will be good as well and having a bad day will usually imply that later days will be bad as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree with you, but often these questions are based on simple assumptions.

Comment: Thanks Candyman you are clearly very skilled with probability problems. I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible and did not specify that each occurrence is unique. I could have used dice or cards perhaps to keep it neutral.

Comment: "*...that each occurrence is unique...*"  Uniqueness has nothing to do with independence.  You should read more about [independence on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).

Answer (score 1):

**I assume that each day is independent from the previous.**

If $1/4$ is the probability to have a "bad day", then $1-1/4= 3/4$ is the probability to have a "good day".

Therefore, in a week, the probability that all days are "good days" is:

$$(3/4)^5.$$

This means that the probability to have at least one "bad day" (negation of "all days are good days") is:

$$1 - (3/4)^5 \simeq 0.7627.$$

---

In general, the probability to have exactly $k$ bad days (out of $5$ working days) is obtained using the [binomial random variable theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$$P(k ~\text{"bad days" in 5 five days}) = {5 \choose k}(1/4)^k(3/4)^{5-k}$$

Similarly, the probability to experience exactly $h$ good days (out of $5$ working days) is:

$$P(h ~\text{"good days" in 5 five days}) = {5 \choose h}(3/4)^h(1/4)^{5-h}$$

Comment: This assumes independence, which is not a safe assumption.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah, you are right. The dean upset at 6pm will be a trouble at 9am of the day after. Anyway, I always assume independence if the OP does not state it explicitly...

Comment: I attempted to figure out the probability of having 2 bad days in a 5 day period and got .0263671875 so I must've done something wrong.